# threading synchronization at high speed

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I have a threading question and what I'd qualify as a modest threading background.

Suppose I have the following (oversimplified) design and behavior:

Object ObjectA - has a reference to object ObjectB and a method MethodA().
Object ObjectB - has a reference to ObjectA, an array of elements ArrayB and a method MethodB().

ObjectA is responsible for instantiating ObjectB. ObjectB.ObjectA will point to ObjectB's instantiator.

Now, whenever some conditions are met, a new element is added in ObjectB.ArrayB and a new thread is started for this element, say ThreadB_x, where x goes from 1 to ObjectB.ArrayB.Length. Each such thread calls ObjectB.MethodB() to pass some data in, which in turn calls ObjectB.ObjectA.MethodA() for data processing.

So multiple threads call the same method ObjectB.MethodB(), and it's very likely that they do so at the very same time. There's a lot of code in MethodB that creates and initializes new objects, so I don't think there are problems there. But then this method calls ObjectB.ObjectA.MethodA(), and I don't have the slightest idea of what's going on in there. Based on the results I get, nothing wrong, apparently, but I'd like to be sure of that.

For now, I enclosed the call to ObjectB.ObjectA.MethodA() in a lock statement inside ObjectB.MethodB(), so I'm thinking this will ensure there are no clashes to the call of MethodA(), though I'm not 100% sure of that. But what happens if each ThreadB_x calls ObjectB.MethodB() a lot of times and very very fast? Will I have a queue of calls waiting for ObjectB.ObjectA.MethodA() to finish?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be much easier if you would *show* the code rather than *describing* it.

Comment: "I don't have the slightest idea of what's going on in there" My thoughts precisely.

Comment: The simple idea is that multiple threads instantiated by one object are trying to access one method from another object at a very high speed. Code is huge, I oversimplified, the above description is more intuitive than the actual code, a diagram would have been even better. I'll figure it out, just thought I'd find new angles here. Thanks. Will post my findings later.

Comment: Look, it's like this.  Multiple threads can call multiple methods through multiple objects in any manner, (assuming the limits of stacks are not reached, like any call sequence).  It's all about the data.  If ObjectA.MethodA() does not use any shared data in ObjectA or elsewhere, you do not need any lock.

Comment: I meant, of course, 'write any shared data'.  Sorry - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to answer because of the lack of information. It depends on the average time spent in `methodA`, how many times this method is called per thread, how many cores are allocated to the process, the OS scheduling policy, to name a few parameters.

All things being equals, when the number of threads grows toward infinity, you can easily imagine that the probability for two threads requesting access to a shared resource simultaneously will tend to one. This probability will grow faster in proportion to the amount of time spent on the shared resource. That intuition is probably the reason of your question.

The main idea of multithreading is to parallelize code which can be effectively computed concurrently, and avoid contention as much as possible. In your setup, if `methodA` is not pure, ie. if it may change the state of the process - or in C++ parlance, if it cannot be made `const`, then it is a source of contention (recall that a function can only be pure if it uses pure functions or constants in its body).

One way of dealing with a shared resource is to protect it with a mutex, as you've done in your code. Another way is to try to turn its use into an async service, with one thread handling it, and others requesting that thread for computation. In effect, you will end up with an explicit queue of requests, but threads doing these requests will be free to work on something else in the mean time. The goal is always to maximize computation time, as opposed to thread management time, which happens each time a thread gets rescheduled.

Of course, it is not always possible to do so, eg. when the result of `methodA` belongs to a strongly ordered chain of computation.